# Scrapy - set delay to retry middleware

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm using `Scrapy-splash` and I have a problem with memory. I can clearly see that memory used by `docker` `python3` is gradually increasing until PC freezes.

Can't figure out why it behaves this way because I have `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=3` and there is no way 3 `HTML` consumes 10GB RAM.

So there is a workaround to set `maxrss` to some reasonable value. When RAM usage has this value, docker is restarted so RAM is flushed.

But the problem is that for the time `docker` is down, `scrapy` continues sending requests so there is a couple of `urls` not scraped. Retry middleware is trying to retry these requests right now and then give up.

```
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.ex.com/eiB3t/ via http://127.0.0.1:8050/execute> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-03-30 14:28:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.ex.com/eiB3t/
```

So I have two questions

1. Do you know a better solution?
2. If not, how can I set `Scrapy` to `retry` request after some time (let's say on minute so `docker` has time to restart)?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a middleware to your Spider ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404391/1544154), [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64903556/1544154)):

```py
# File: middlewares.py

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred


class DelayedRequestsMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        delay_s = request.meta.get('delay_request_by', None)
        if not delay_s:
            return

        deferred = Deferred()
        reactor.callLater(delay_s, deferred.callback, None)
        return deferred
```

Which you could later use in your Spider like this:

```py
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'middlewares.DelayedRequestsMiddleware': 123},
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        # This request will have itself delayed by 5 seconds
        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/', 
                             meta={'delay_request_by': 5})
        # This request will not be delayed
        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/')

    def parse(self, response):
        ...  # Process results here
```

Related method is described here: [Method #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64903556/1544154)

Answer (score -1):

1. A more elaborate solution could be to set up a Kubernetes cluster in which you have multiple replicas running. This way you avoid having a failure of just 1 container impacting your scraping job.
2. I don't think it's easy to configure a waiting time only for retries. You could play with DOWNLOAD_DELAY (but this will impact delay between all requests), or set the RETRY_TIMES to a higher value than the default of 2.